# How to receive a specific value in Firebase database (Problems reading or receivng data)

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-realtime-database

I need to receive these two values from my database 
and i need to put these values in a marker 
And I do not know how to put the received latitude and longitude of the database to a marker

[image: db]

this is my methods than i use:

```
          public static DatabaseReference getPostRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(Constantes.POSTS_KEY);
}
public static Query getPostQuery() {
    return getPostRef().orderByChild(Constantes.TIME_CREATED_KEY);
}
public static DatabaseReference getMyPostRef() {
    return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constantes.MY_POSTS)
            .child(getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".", ","));
}

// USER ID
public static String getUid() {
    String path = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().toString();
    return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
}
```

and i use this for send the data

```
 FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().child(postUid).setValue(mPost);
```

this is my model class:

```
 public class Post implements Serializable {

private String photoPortadaUrl;

private String organizadoPor;

private String mes;
private String dia;

private String hora;
private String minutos;

private String titulo;
private String descripicion;
private String costo;

private double latitud;
private double longitud;

public Post(){

}

public Post(String photoPortadaUrl, String organizadoPor, String mes, String dia, String hora, String minutos, String titulo, String descripicion, String costo, double latitud, double longitud) {
    this.photoPortadaUrl = photoPortadaUrl;
    this.organizadoPor = organizadoPor;
    this.mes = mes;
    this.dia = dia;
    this.hora = hora;
    this.minutos = minutos;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.descripicion = descripicion;
    this.costo = costo;
    this.latitud = latitud;
    this.longitud = longitud;
}


public String getPhotoPortadaUrl() {
    return photoPortadaUrl;
}

public void setPhotoPortadaUrl(String photoPortadaUrl) {
    this.photoPortadaUrl = photoPortadaUrl;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getOrganizadoPor() {
    return organizadoPor;
}

public void setOrganizadoPor(String organizadoPor) {
    this.organizadoPor = organizadoPor;
}

public String getMes() {
    return mes;
}

public void setMes(String mes) {
    this.mes = mes;
}

public String getDia() {
    return dia;
}

public void setDia(String dia) {
    this.dia = dia;
}

public String getHora() {
    return hora;
}

public void setHora(String hora) {
    this.hora = hora;
}

public String getMinutos() {
    return minutos;
}

public void setMinutos(String minutos) {
    this.minutos = minutos;
}

public String getDescripicion() {
    return descripicion;
}

public void setDescripicion(String descripicion) {
    this.descripicion = descripicion;
}

public String getCosto() {
    return costo;
}

public void setCosto(String costo) {
    this.costo = costo;
}

public double getLatitud() {
    return latitud;
}

public void setLatitud(double latitud) {
    this.latitud = latitud;
}

public double getLongitud() {
    return longitud;
}

public void setLongitud(double longitud) {
    this.longitud = longitud;
}
```

}

But to receive the data or read them I do this: i put the relevant code:

```
            public class NavActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Post mPost;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav);
  mPost = new Post();
 }


 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
   FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().child(postuid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        mPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);

        // HERE IS THE ERROR
        //When I try to read the data it gives me an exception which I will put down


        /* 
         I try with this 
          but i get the same exception

           Post LPOst = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);

           Log.d("Dep", LPOst.getTitulo());
         */

        Log.d("Dep", mPost.getTitulo());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});



 }
```

}

i get this exception:

```
      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.octacorp.octa.strank.models.Post.getTitulo()' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.octacorp.octa.strank.Activities.NavActivity$5.onDataChange(NavActivity.java:333)
```

how can i did?

Comment: How does this relate to your prevoius question about the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701713/how-to-receive-latitude-and-longitude-data-stored-from-firebase-and-put-it-in-a. You never accepted or provided an answer there, so is this still the same problem?

Comment: I think I can put the latitude and longitude data to the marker, but I do not know how to receive that data, I'm trying with a singleValueEventListener ()  @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen i try this, using like the documentation but doesnt works, i try Post lPost = dataSpanshot.getValue(Post.class); but i get a NullPointerException, the data is in the Firebase is not null and the lPost object is instanciated

Comment: Please add the code that reads the data (and throws the exception) to the question. There's a handy edit link right under the question for that purpose. I also recommend you read how to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), since: the less code is needed to reproduce the problem, the more likely it is that someone will sport the cause.

Comment: HI @FrankvanPuffelen this worked with a ChildEvenListener(); thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need a value event listener for this. If you don't want the data to be fetched every time it changes,  you can use a single event listener.

Comment: Thanks but how can I implement it to receive latitude and longitude data?

Comment: Point you database reference to the node, you want to fetch and add a value event listener. If the value for the node doesn't exist then you will get null. Lots of tutorials on firebase docs page.

Comment: i try this ` FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                 mPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);

                latlgn6 = new LatLng(mPost.getLatitud(), mPost.getLongitud());

                mkOption = new MarkerOptions().position(latlgn6).title(mPost.getTitulo());




            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        }); mMap.addMarker(mkOption);`